# Can PHP script continue to process even if user closes their browser?

Tags: php, background

I have to execute a method in background; the whole script takes around 30 minutes to finish. I make this as background process, my script is still working after the page is refreshed or close browser. But how to keep executing script if user shuts down their system?

Comment: Do you mean the user shuts down their browser, or they shut down the server?

Comment: ^ @halfer That sounds like attack on the server

Comment: @VeeeneX: I think the OP means simply that the browser is shut down. But they could be talking about an office that shuts down and computers/servers are turned off by users who normally access them via a browser (and that the script needs to resume when the machine is turned back on). I am sure he/she will clarify.

Comment: I want, if user shut down their operating system. still php code should be executed. is it possible?

Comment: I think his running the code on a local server on the clients computer. And if its that then he should refactor his code to be resumable and make it pause once the user turns off the system and resume once he starts it again

Comment: "if user shut down their operating system" - do you mean the browser operating system or the server operating system? I have assumed the browser, and have clarified your question accordingly.

Comment: @halfer : browser operating system. shut down will be done at customer end. Customer dont know about server. like if you accessing my website on your opering system than you can shutdown your system not server.  If you are requesting to perform a action, it will take 30 mins. and after that a mail will be send to you. why you want to just sit and wait for email when you know it will come after 30 mins. You may shutdown and go. I want if you shut down your system , still this process should be running. right now , its terminating in my testing. 
Hope i am clear now. please suggest something

Comment: OK. You can do this with a cron or a job queue. For the cron, the user clicks a button that sets a database flag, and every five minutes the cron checks the database. If the flag is set, it starts its 30 minute operation.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to design the script in such a way that is resumable. This way, when the machine is rebooted a daemon can resume your script and it would continue working.

Of course (and I assume you knew that), you can't make the script continue to run on a machine that is turned off.

Comment: i found that register_shutdown_function can do something like this. but when i put this in code , whole script stop working. please guide

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by shut down the system? He turns off the server or logs out of your application?
If its the first you could set up a cronjob to run when the user is about to shut down the system. You could code it into your "exit" button (if you have one) and scheduel a cron job to execute your script the next day. If its the latest the  just use an asynchronic script in php.

Comment: i found that register_shutdown_function can do something like this. but when i put this in code , whole script stop working. please guide.

Comment: Im not to clear on what exactly your trying to do. Is the user shuting down the server? Or are your running on a local through xamp or something like that? Or is he just logging out  of your site?

Comment: I am working on a website. there is a user request process, which will take around 30 mins to finish. enough time to do anything else. So i modified my code so that, script will continue executing if user close the tabs or browser, But if user need to shut down his operating system so this process is killed. Thats i don't want.

Comment: But is the code running in the users machine? Or is it in a remote server? Because normal websites dont stop working if the user shutsdown his machine.

Comment: On user machine. all user request process is stop working after shutdown in my website. Please explain how other website is still working. i ready don't have knowledge about it.

Comment: Normally php script run on servers, out of the clients machine. So the user shutting down dosent affect the php server. Go with the cron job suggestion then make your code to be able to stop. It is not an easy job and if your just starting with programming it will probably be ver difficult. The easy solution is to move your code to a server. Hosting today is really cheap and its safer than having your code in your clients machine.

Answer (score 0):

The script cannot continue if the system is shut down. There is no system that "works" so the php script can continue it's job :)

Comment: *user shutdown the system* OP means user system

Comment: That makes a lot more sense :)